# Ethernet not detected in Ubuntu 16.04, but port light blinks

Tags: networking, 16.04, ethernet, lan

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS version till yesterday I was getting the LAN connection. Now it is not showing up when LAN wire is connected to the port. The light in the port blinks as it was before.

```
ifconfig -a
```

gives the following output:

```
lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:1213 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1213 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:97282 (97.2 KB)  TX bytes:97282 (97.2 KB)

wlo1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:6d:57:b8:3b:a2  
      inet addr:192.168.0.18  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::602:739c:2a9f:19c2/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:5779 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4805 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:4504918 (4.5 MB)  TX bytes:1078354 (1.0 MB)
```

**eth0** is not showing and no other ethernet device interface is being detected. I have tried the same in a live session of Ubuntu 16.10 which returns the output as **lo** and **wlo1** only.

***Update***

The output of **lspci** is as follows:

```
  00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM      Controller (rev 09)
  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
  00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
  00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
  00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
  00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
  00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
  00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
  00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
  00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM75 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
 00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
 00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
 02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
 03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

**Conclusion**

My ethernet adapter might be damaged.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 There is no output for that command

Comment: OK. Then post `lspci`.

Comment: The Ethernet adapter is disabled in BIOS or broken.

Comment: In bios where will be the option to enable it? Broken means?

Comment: In bios it looks like "onboard LAN" or something loke that. It depends in the BIOS. Broken means broken.

Comment: If it is broken I have to replace it?

Comment: If it is a separate card, you can replace it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53939/discussion-between-supremum-and-pilot6).